# how to covert b3dm file to obj file

Tags: 3d, mesh, web3js, cesiumjs, data-transform

There are many tools converting the **b3dm** file to **obj** file, but I can not find any tool that can convert **obj** file to **b3dm** file.

Thank you very much!